# What is the difference between ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock and Response.Write?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "js", "alert('Wrong Login Attempt..!');", true);

Response.Write(script language='javascript'>@alert('Wrong Login attempt');/script>");
```

Though both yield the same result, I want to know the difference between the two.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ScriptManager will ensure that the script is only included once, provided that you use the same key for it each time.